# How to get the matched string

Tags: python

I am using any() in python

```
from inActivePhrase import phrase

detailslist=[]

for detail in detailslist:
    inactive = any(term in detail for term in phrase)
```

Where the phrase will have the list of strings like below

```
phrase = ["not active","Closed",etc..]
```

The function is working fine. But i want to get the phrase which is present in the detail.

**Example :**

```
  detail = "this is not active"
  inactive = any(term in detail for term in phrase)
   if inactive:
        print('matched phrase' + term) //how can i do this
```

in which the "not active" is the matched phrase. So i want to print it.

How can i do that. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

you could have several term matching detail

```
detail = "this is not active"
inactive = [term for term in phrase if term in detail]
if inactive:
    print('matched phrases' + inactive)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `next`, which will iterate and stop as soon as it finds the first match. If it finds nothing, it returns the default value (`None` in this case):

```
detail = "this is not active"
inactive = next((term for term in phrase if term in detail), None)
if inactive:
    print('matched phrase' + inactive)
```

Comment: Found the problem, Working fine.